# Custom font not loaded with webpack/sass

Tags: reactjs, fonts, sass, webpack

We have a large project where we're trying to implement ITCSS pattern (which works just fine) and add to it a custom icon font created by our graphists.

Here is the folder structure (not exhaustive):

```
.
├── build
│   └── webpack.config.js
└── src
    ├── components                           # Using React
    │   ├── test.jsx
    │   └── test.scss
    └── styles
        ├── _objects                         # Components style reusable
        │   ├── _all.scss
        │   └── table.scss
        ├── _settings                        # Global variables
        │   ├── _all.scss
        │   ├── _custom-icons.scss           # Define icon font (see below)
        │   ├── _custom-icons-variables.scss # Define icon codes
        │   ├── _colors.scss                 # Define colors
        │   ├── _predefined-colors.scss      # Define brand colors
        │   └── _theme.scss                  # Define specific theme
        ├── _tools                           # Mixins / helpers
        │   ├── _all.scss
        │   ├── _animation.scss
        │   ├── _breakpoints.scss
        │   └── _transition.scss
        ├── _wins                            # Overrides
        │   ├── _all.scss
        │   ├── _display.scss
        │   ├── _position.scss
        │   └── _text.scss
        ├── assets
        │   └── fonts
        │       ├── custom-icons.eot
        │       ├── custom-icons.svg
        │       ├── custom-icons.ttf
        │       └── custom-icons.woff
        ├── _base.scss                       # HTML Selectors
        ├── _generic.scss                    # Reset (normalize)
        └── main.scss                        # Loads everything
```

OK, that's a pretty heavy file structure, but it does the job regarding what we want to achieve!

We started our app upon the react-redux-starter-kit by davezuko. We tweaked webpack config file to match our needs but didn't change the style part, so you can refer to the [webpack.config.js from GitHub](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/build/webpack.config.js).

Now, here are our files:

**_custom-icons-variables.scss**

```
$fontPath: "./assets/fonts" !default;

$aw-happy: "\e9df";
$aw-smile: "\e9e1";
$aw-tongue: "\e9e3";
$aw-sad: "\e9e5";
$aw-wink: "\e9e7";
$aw-grin: "\e9e9";
$aw-cool: "\e9eb";
$aw-angry: "\e9ed";
…
```

**_custom-icons.scss**

The custom icon font is relying on Semantic-UI font icon styling.

```
@import "custom-icons-variables";

$fontName: 'custom-icons';

$fallbackSRC: url("#{$fontPath}/#{$fontName}.eot");
$src:
  url("#{$fontPath}/#{$fontName}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  url("#{$fontPath}/#{$fontName}.woff") format('woff'),
  url("#{$fontPath}/#{$fontName}.ttf") format('truetype'),
  url("#{$fontPath}/#{$fontName}.svg?##{$fontName}") format('svg')
;

@font-face {
  font-family: $fontName;
  src:  $fallbackSRC;
  src:  $src;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

i.icon.aw {
  font-family: $fontName !important;
}

.aw-happy {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-happy;
  }
}
.aw-smile {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-smile;
  }
}
.aw-tongue {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-tongue;
  }
}
.aw-sad {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-sad;
  }
}
.aw-wink {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-wink;
  }
}
.aw-grin {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-grin;
  }
}
.aw-cool {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-cool;
  }
}
.aw-angry {
  &:before {
    content: $aw-angry;
  }
}
…
```

**main.scss**

Everything in here is global so we avoid webpack adding a hash and allow us to use direct class names in our components (see below for an example).

```
:global {
  @import "_settings/all";
  @import "_settings/custom-icons";
  @import "_tools/all";
  @import "generic";
  @import "base";
  @import "_objects/all";
  @import "_wins/all";
}
```

**test.jsx**

Here you can see we use both global and scoped styles.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import s from './test.scss'

export default class Test extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className={s['test']}>
        <i className='icon aw aw-happy'></i>
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**test.scss**

Yes, for each component that uses our brand colors, we need to reimport the Sass file… I don't know if it's a bad thing, but it works :)

```
@import "src/styles/_settings/all";

.test {
  background: $brown;
  color: $white_smoke;
}
```

---

Now that background is set, here is the problem:

The `aw-happy` icon is rendered as a square (like when your font is not loaded…) and I can't manage to make it work, I tried everything I could after browsing tons of resources :/

We are using [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) which is built and then bundled with webpack, so I tried to add the `@font-face` rule to the `semantic.min.css` and also moved fonts files to semantic folder:

**semantic.min.css**

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'custom-icons';
   src:  url(themes/default/assets/fonts/custom-icons.eot);
   src:  url(themes/default/assets/fonts/custom-icons.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
   url(themes/default/assets/fonts/custom-icons.woff) format('woff'),
   url(themes/default/assets/fonts/custom-icons.ttf) format('truetype'),
   url(themes/default/assets/fonts/custom-icons.svg?#custom-icons) format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
 }
 // Semantic stuff…
```

And… It works!

I wonder if I'd better build and serve this custom font the same way we do with semantic, but it's annoying to move all the process apart from global styles stuff.

Any idea on how to solve this by keeping all the Sass/Webpack stuff?

Comment: I think Webpack just fails to pick up the font files because you use variables inside your `url()` things. Try using only simple strings, I think that should just work.

Comment: I already tried it and this doesn't work either… :/ I tried both `url(assets/fonts/custom-icons.eot)` and `url("assets/fonts/custom-icons.eot")`! Also, I tried to leave this in the `$src` and `$fallbackSrc` but also to write it directly in the @font-face definition…

Comment: I looked at the Resource panel of Chrome Dev Tools and I do not see my font loaded, Furthermore, when I look into the Sources panel and go to webpack:// sources, I see my fonts are exports like this `module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "src/styles/assets/fonts/custom-icons.eot";` (same for all versions, ie: eot/svg/ttf/woff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I've found by browsing closed bug of react-redux-starter-kit project:

I moved the `@font-face` definition to `main.scss`, above `:global`:

**main.scss**

```
$font-path: 'styles/assets/fonts';
$font-name: 'custom-icons';

$fallback-src: url("#{$font-path}/#{$font-name}.eot");
$src:
  url("#{$font-path}/#{$font-name}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
  url("#{$font-path}/#{$font-name}.woff") format('woff'),
  url("#{$font-path}/#{$font-name}.ttf") format('truetype'),
  url("#{$font-path}/#{$font-name}.svg?##{$font-name}") format('svg')
;

@font-face {
  font-family: $font-name;
  src:  $fallback-src;
  src:  $src;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It also worked when I defined `$font-path` to `../styles/assets/fonts` but not to `./assets/fonts`.

It's a known bug that is [referenced at GitHub](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/issues/403) but davezuko didn't dig into it at this time.